# How can I move into button bound then it will highlighted? (I upload the video)

Tags: ios, button, touch

http://youtu.be/TzPk4_hKozs
In this video, I made 5 button on view control.
When I touch button1 , it is highlighted.

I move my finger to button2 button 3 button4 button5...but there are no highlighted.

I wanna let the button highlighted when I move into their bounds.

How can I do?

please help me, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to get that behavior with UIButton, but you can get it with not a lot of work.

1. Create a UIView subclass that can be set to be highlighted or not.
2. Add a UILongPressGestureRecognizer to the view displaying all 5 of the new views.
3. Specify an action and create a method to match, like -(void)longTouch:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture.
4. When the gesture state is UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan or UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged, determine what view your touch is over and highlight that view and unhighlight the rest.